# Multiple Command Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, commandbinding

Is it possible to bind the multiple commands to the button.

I have a user control, which i am calling in my main application (parent application).

I want to handle a click command on both the controls (the user control as well as on the main window). However i am only able to get one.

Is there any way in which i can get this.

Any help is really appreciated.

Code Snippet:

```
public class MainWindowFooterCommands
{
    public static readonly RoutedUICommand FooterClickLocalCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Local Button Command", "FooterClickLocalCommand", typeof(MainWindowFooterCommands));
}

private void MainWindowFooterBindCommands()
{
    CommandBinding cmdBindingBXClick = new CommandBinding(MainWindowFooterCommands.FooterClickLocalCommand);
        cmdBindingBXClick.Executed += ClickCommandHandler;
        CommandBindings.Add(cmdBindingBXClick);
}


void ClickCommandHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do Something
}


//Parent Control holding an instance of the footer control.
class MainWindow {

    public MainWindow() 
    {
        CommandBinding cmdBindingBXClick1 = new CommandBinding(MainWindowFooterCommands.BXClickMainWindowCommand);
        cmdBindingBXClick1.Executed += LoadParent;  
        CommandBindings.Add(cmdBindingBXClick1);
    }

        public void LoadParent(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {   
        LoadParentWindow();
        }
}
```

Regards,
Tushar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding two commands to one button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803913/binding-two-commands-to-one-button)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be trying to aggregate multiple commands, which is a natural thing to want to do.

If you are using Prism, there is a class builtin for this called the CompositeCommand (scroll down a bit): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921126.aspx

Otherwise, Josh Smith has a very good article on his implementation called a "Command Group": http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/commandgroup.aspx

There are some very nice scenarios you can rollup like this (for instance, "Save All").  A good tool for your bag of tricks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK WPF doesnt offer anything out of the box to support multiple commandbindings at various levels, but you could try the following:

```
void ClickCommandHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IInputElement parent = (IInputElement) LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)sender);
    MainWindowFooterCommands.BXClickMainWindowCommand.Execute(e.Parameter, parent);
}
```

You might have to test whether your parent really is an IInputElement, though.