# Binding two commands to one button?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, browser, command

I have a tab control contains two tabs, one shows me the messages of a running process and the other shows me a web page!

I have three buttons (start, stop and clear)
when I press start the process run and the messages show up.

What I need is wen I press Start button, both tabs, shows me the required content. That's mean I need two bind two commands to the same button

Do you know how to bind for 1 button two commands?

I'm using MVVM, and I'm new in MVVM.

```
<Button Content="Start" Command="{Binding StartProcess_Command }" Height="25" Width="60" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10"/>
<Button Content="Stop"  Command="{Binding StopProcess_Command}" Height="25" Width="60" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10"/>
<Button Content="Clear" Command="{Binding ClearBtn_Command}" Height="25" Width="60" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10"/>
<telerik:RadTabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="10">
    <telerik:RadTabItem Header="Maestro" IsSelected="{Binding Path=MaestroSelected}">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <local:WPFBrowser/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </telerik:RadTabItem>
    <telerik:RadTabItem Header="Messages">
        <Grid Background="LightGray">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=output_process,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </telerik:RadTabItem>
</telerik:RadTabControl >
```

And this is the WPFBrowser.cs code:

```
         public WPFBrowser()
            {
                ServerString = "localhost"; //defualt value
                PortString = "9999"; //default value
                this.refreshCommand = new Lunch_Maestro.ViewModel.Command(DoRefreshCommand);
                m_WPFBrowser = new WebBrowser()
                {
                    HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                    VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch
                };

                m_WPFBrowser.Navigated += WPFBrowser_Navigated;

                this.Content = m_WPFBrowser;
            }

            private void WPFBrowser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
            {
                this.HideScriptErrors(m_WPFBrowser, true);
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// Found this link with interesting scenerios for script erros...
            /// http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f686de1-8884-4a8d-8ec5-ae4eff8ce6db/new-wpf-webbrowser-how-do-i-suppress-script-errors?forum=wpf
            /// </summary>
            public void HideScriptErrors(WebBrowser wb, bool Hide)
            {
                FieldInfo fiComWebBrowser = typeof(WebBrowser).GetField("_axIWebBrowser2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                if (fiComWebBrowser == null) return;

                object objComWebBrowser = fiComWebBrowser.GetValue(wb);

                if (objComWebBrowser == null) return;

                objComWebBrowser.GetType().InvokeMember("Silent", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, objComWebBrowser, new object[] { Hide });

            }


            private void DoRefreshCommand()
            {
                m_WPFBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://" + ServerString + ":" + PortString + "/"));
            }

            private bool _maestroSelected;
            public bool MaestroSelected
            {
                get { return _maestroSelected; }
                set
                {
                    _maestroSelected = value;
                    if (_maestroSelected == true)
                        m_WPFBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://" + ServerString + ":" + PortString + "/"));
                    OnPropertyChanged("MaestroSelected");
                }
            }

            private readonly WebBrowser m_WPFBrowser;

            private string _serverString;
            public string ServerString
            {
                get { return _serverString; }
                set
                {
                    _serverString = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ServerString");
                }
            }

            private string _portString;
            public string PortString
            {
                get { return _portString; }
                set
                {
                    _portString = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("PortString");
                }
            }

            private Lunch_Maestro.ViewModel.Command refreshCommand;
            public Lunch_Maestro.ViewModel.Command RefreshCommand
            {
                get { return refreshCommand; }
            }
// and Inotify property changes here
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990113/MultiBinding-for-WPF-Command-Combining

Answer (score 13):

you can call multiple commands like this:

```
// xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"

<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Cmd1}" />
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Cmd2}" />
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Cmd3}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

this will also allow you to control the command execution order if you ever need to

PS: you just need to install `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` NuGet package.

Answer (score 8):

You want to click one `Button` and run two pieces of code... it really doesn't sound that complicated. Using one of the available [`RelayCommand`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx), the problem could be fixed as simply as this:

```
public ICommand SomeCommand
{
    get { return new ActionCommand(action) => { RunFirstFunction(action); 
        RunSecondFunction(action) }, canExecute => someCondition); }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SomeObject}">
    Click Me
</Button>
```

`ActionCommand` is my own form of the `RelayCommand`, but all of the `delegate ICommand` implementations are roughly equal and could work in this way. The `CommandParameter` value comes into the code as the `action` variable and is passed through to the two functions.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [CompositeCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.commands.compositecommand%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) from the [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) Framework.
Create an additional CompositeCommand in your viewmodel, register both ordinary commands with this CompositeCommand and bind the button to the CompositeCommand.

See the [Prism documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/composite-commands.html) on page 130 on how to work with CompositeCommands.

Your app needs to reference Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll which is included in the Prism package.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is with WPF, buttons can easily do two things - by the Click event and the Command event. Limitation: only two things. Advantage: Using the power of the standard button so you need no other NuGet packages or third party references.

In your Xaml:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource CancelButtonStyle}"
        Command="{Binding CancelScenarioCommand}"
        Click="On_Close_Button" />
```

In your Xaml.cs code behind:

```
private void On_Close_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```

In your ViewModel (VM):

```
public ICommand CancelScenarioCommand { get; }

public ThisViewModel()
{
   CancelScenarioCommand = new RelayCommand(OnCancelScenario);
}

private void OnCancelScenario()
{
    // do something spectacular
}
```