# Two commands to one button

Tags: c#, wpf, command, modern-ui

I'd like to bind two actions to a ModernUI link: when clicked, it should a) trigger a `RelayCommand` and b) navigate. I have googled and read but could not find a solution. So far, I only made it to either bind or navigate, but not both..

E.g. in the sample ModernUI application, Navigation takes place like this:

```
                <Button Content="introduction" Margin="0,0,4,0"
                        Command="mui:LinkCommands.NavigateLink"
                        CommandParameter="/Pages/Introduction.xaml"/>
```

But then the `Command` property is already used, so how could I attach my second `Command` to it?

```
                <Button Content="introduction"
                        Command="{Binding MyCommand}">
```

I've also tried using a `ListBox`, where I can use the `SelectedItem` property, but this one has no `Command` property.

I'd be thankful for a hint!

Comment: why not call the LinkCommand within your MyCommand in your viewmodel?

Comment: I've tried that, too, but got stuck when the navigation tab bar did not reflect the current page and also thought that this would be a violation of MVVM ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding two commands to one button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803913/binding-two-commands-to-one-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25808/Aggregating-WPF-Commands-with-CommandGroup) site shows an implementation of a list of `Command`s that presents itself to be one command. That way, calling one would call the others.

In fact, the class just implements `ICommand` *and* an `ObservableCollection` of `Command`s that get executed when called.

That seems a proper solution for your problem.