# Execute Two RelayCommands On One Button Press - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, visibility

I have a button that allows the user to register an account. When the user presses the button I have a relay command execute a method that submits their details to the database. If successful, I then want the user to be transferred to the login screen.

I have used EnumStateVisibility, when I used a converter that triggers UserControls visible or hidden.

**Here is the code that I have:**

**Submit account details to database on press**

[image: Submit account details button]

```
/// <summary>
        /// Submits users details to database and checks criteria
        /// </summary>
        public RelayCommand SubmitRegisterAccountDetails
        {
            get
            {
                SubmitAccountDetails submit = new SubmitAccountDetails();
                return new RelayCommand(param => submit.SubmitLoginUserDetails(EmailAddress, Mail, Password, CurrentState));
            }
        }




// Enum State to visibility converter, toggles login and register views on and off in window
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                LoginVisibilityStates state = (LoginVisibilityStates)value;
                LoginVisibilityStates para = (LoginVisibilityStates)Enum.Parse(typeof(LoginVisibilityStates), parameter.ToString());

                if (state == para)
                    return Visibility.Visible;
                else
                    return Visibility.Hidden;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }



// Logic to switch UserControl when user presses a different button, with
// this relaycommand set as the command and "Login" or "Register" as the CommandParameter

    private LoginVisibilityStates _currentState;
        public LoginVisibilityStates CurrentState
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentState;
            }
            set
            {
                _currentState = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentState");
            }
        }

        #region Commands
        public RelayCommand SwitchCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(ChangeState);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public void ChangeState(object parameter)
        {
            switch (parameter.ToString())
            {
                case "Register":
                    CurrentState = LoginVisibilityStates.Register;
                    break;
                case "Login":
                    CurrentState = LoginVisibilityStates.Login;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why don't make a new Command/Method, that calls the other two? Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803913/binding-two-commands-in-one-button-wpf-mvvm

Answer (score 1):

You can only execute one command but in the `Execute` method of this command you can do whatever you want, including invoking another command, set a property or call a method:

```
return new RelayCommand(param => 
{
    submit.SubmitLoginUserDetails(EmailAddress, Mail, Password, CurrentState);
    //set the property or do whatever here:
    LoginVisibilityStates = LoginVisibilityStates.Login;
});
```