# Multiple commands in Button.CommandBindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

```
<Button.CommandBindings>
<CommandBinding  Command="{x:Static materialdesign:DrawerHost.OpenDrawerCommand}"/>
<CommandBinding  Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
</Button.CommandBindings>
```

Im trying to trigger 2 different commands on a button click. One is set from a UI Library I am using and the other one is mine.

I Get the following error :

A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Command' property of type 'CommandBinding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.'

Does someone know how to achieve this ? Does Xaml even allow it ?

Comment: Why don't you just implement one command that does all the things you want done? You can factor common code in the existing commands out so it can be shared.

Comment: The first command is used by the UI Library and its responsible for some animation on the UI side and I cannot access it. I am also using Prism & DI to link my views and view-models so if I just implement UI functions in my Viewmodel it will defeat the whole architecture purpose, I want to keep the UI Commands and the ViewModel Commands separate to keep my Viewmodels testable.

Comment: Does it work for any of the two CommandBinding entries when it's the only one?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22804987/5265292, maybe it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

- Create an object implementing `ICommand` that contains a list of command entries. The object then just calls all the commands in sequence in the `Execute` method.
- Bind the `Button.Command` to an instance of this class.

e.g. XAML

```
<Button.Command>
    <CommandList>
         <CommandEntry Command="{x:Static ...}"/>
         <CommandEntry Command="{Binding ...}"/>
    </CommandList>
</Button.Command>
```

`CommandEntry` needs to be a `DependencyObject` and `Command` needs to be a dependency property to support bindings.

Comment: I get an error saying CommandList doesn't support direct content, Can you please elaborate on how to implement your idea? this is exactly what's needed.

Comment: @NoLandsMan: For that you need to use the `ContentPropertyAttribute` on the `CommandList` class to reference your list property. I think the property should be of type `IList` or `IList<CommandEntry>` for this to work.